# Suppose $G$ is group of order $p^k$ for $p$ prime and $k$ positive integer. Prove $G$ must contain an element with an order of $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated, p-groups

Suppose $G$ is group of order $p^k$ for $p$ prime and $k$ positive integer.
Prove $G$ must contain an element with an order of $p$.

---

I have proven that every element of $G$ must be of order $p^j$, $0\le j\le k$.

I was trying to put together a proof where some $g\in G$ generates a cyclic subgroup $H$. Since $H$ cyclic, then it's generated by $g$ from $G$ so $|g|=p^j$ for some $j$. So some element $h\in H$ is $h=g^r$, some $0\le r\le j$. And, $|h|=|g^r|= \frac{|g|}{gcd(r,|g|)}$, where $g$ is generator of $H$ so $|g|=p^j$. Then, taking $r=^j-1$, have $|h|=|p^j|/|p^{j-1}|=p$. So some $h\in H$ is $h\in G$ with $|h|=p$.

Comment: If $g$ has order $p^j$, then what's the order of $g^{p^{j-1}}$?

Comment: This is a special case of Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson if $|g|=p^j$, then $|g^{p^{j-1}}|=p^{j-1}$

Comment: @Shaun the theorem hasn't been explicitly been defined yet in class. I used Lagrange Theorem for for showing every element in $G$ has order $|g|=p^j$ for some $j$

Comment: What is $(g^{p^{j-1}})^p$, eddie?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  $\left(g^p^{^{j-1}}\right)^p\:=\:g^{p^j}$

Comment: I take it you mean $g^{p^j}$. And what does that equal, if $g$ has order $p^j$, eddie?

Comment: @GerryMyerson every element $g\in G$ has $|g|=p^j$. I'm not sure if I'm in the wrong direction with this

Comment: Haven't we just proved that $g^{p^{j-1}}$ has order $p$? And isn't that what your question is asking for?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't completely understand. I'm a bit confused as to how it's proved

Comment: Write $h=g^{p^{j-1}}$. We've seen that $h^p=g^{p^j}$. If $g$ has order $p^j$, then this means $h^p=1$. So either $h$ is the identity, or else it has order $p$. But $h$ is not the identity, because $g$ has order $p^j$. (I'm assuming $j>1$; if $j=1$, then there's nothing to prove).

Comment: @GerryMyerson is this similar to what I tried to do?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you were trying to do, since your very first sentence ("I have proven that every element of $G$ must be of order $p^j$, $0\le j\le1$") is already false.

Comment: typo, it's supposed to say $\le k$ not $\le 1$

Comment: And then it says, "I was trying to put together a proof where some $g\in G$ generates a cyclic subgroup $H$," but of course every element of every subgroup generates a cyclic subgroup. After that, I stopped reading, and hoped you could make something of what I was writing. Your answers didn't reassure me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think i understand what you were showing and I retried the problem and i think i figured it out

Comment: Good! You can post an answer, then.